# C Practice Test Ints and Char Arrays

Tags: c

I was asked this on a practice test, that has no answers posted. I have no way to test the code, but it has confused me. Can you please help me out with not only understanding the answer, but why.

```
int foo() {
    int a = 1;
    char b[] = "zapples";
    a = *(b + 1);
    if (a == 'a') return 1;
    else return 0;
}
What does foo return? ____
```

Comment: What do you don't understand?

Comment: What it returns. Specifically the line `a = *(b + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have they taught you how C pointers work?

I'm not going to give you a straight answer, but think about this:

`b` has the starting address of string "zapples". This means that `b[0]` points to "z". Another notation for this is `*(b + 0)`, that is, "the value contained at address `b`, with an offset of `0`). With this information, what is the value of `*(b + 1)`?

This should be enough to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It will return 1.

The line `a = *(b + 1)` is the important one. It takes b as a pointer to the first element in the array and adds one so it points to the second. It is then dereferenced so that the value at that address 'a' is assigned to the variable `a`.

Comment: This is homework, try not to give away the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that asking for help meant they had tried all they could.

Comment: It is actually not nessassarly homework, I just used the tag, because practice test is not a tag, and the question deals with schoolwork. I am studying for the final, and just wanted an explanation. Thank You for your answer.